# #VALUE Error when using AGGREGATE in a formula (EXCEL)

Tags: excel, excel-formula, aggregate

Like the title says I am getting a #value error when using the AGGREGATE function. I am using it in conjunction with INDEX to return matched rows based upon an entered value (Customer ID).

```
=INDEX(Equipment[Equipment ID],AGGREGATE(15,3,(Equipment[Customer ID]=$B$3)/(Equipment[Customer ID]=$B$3)*(ROW(Equipment[Customer ID])-ROW(Equipment[#Headers])),ROWS(Equipment!$B$2:B2)))
```

The INDEX portion of the formula is working just fine and returning the correct values. I have also used the same formula to create a section that looks up contacts (using the same formula) and that works perfectly.

Here is a view of some of the data:
[Partial Data from Equipment Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XOKgX.png)

Comment: The formula seemed to work for me. It returned a number rather than an error. If you can explain what you are trying to do, we might be able to provide some alternatives

Comment: @Christopher - A lookup to return all equipment information based upon the entered customer ID. Did you just leave all the data as being general format? I have tried that and also tried changing it to text. I have tried copying the data and pasting it to a new sheet as values only also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Needed to force the data into value format by using the VALUE() function. Copying and pasting as values did not work. This fixed the error occurring with the AGGREGATE part of the formula.